# SQL Server Full Text Search Performance

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have an Ecommerce/Online Shopping site with around 2 million items(MS SQL Server DB). It has various products and i want to implement a search functionality for it. The search could be anything like "White shirt" , "Black Shoes", "Leather Belt" so on.

Please advise me about the performance of full text search and what are the pros/cons to using this.

Currently my database sometimes using 50% to 60%  CPU. Does full text search helps me to reduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Full-Text Search (index) is better than just the non-clustered / clustered index in your case coz SQL Server able to use much more effective algorithms of search so it reduces consumption of RAM coz most of the operations performs there. My experience isn't able to estimate properly CPU usage but it seems to me that Full-Text Search affects CPU poorly. So this doesn't resolve CPU performance issue.

Also, check that *IsFullTextInstalled* was installed:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled');
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what should I have to do to reduce cpu usage? indexing or need to optimize the queries using execution plan. As I am using LIKE operator it looks that's why CPU usage is too high.

Comment: Investigate your problem query using this checklist https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2017/07/30/sql-high-cpu-troubleshooting-checklist/ Which operations utilize the most CPU resources?