# SQL - Quick way to search large datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where my SQL database will be storing potentially hundreds of millions of records.

Currently, a single table stores records for several devices. I need to quickly return information for a single device. What would be the quickest way to query only the records for a certain device?

I tried using subqueries as below, however in testing this did not improve functionality, neither did indexing, though that may be because I have done it incorrectly.

One of my queries is:

```
SELECT SINGLEDEVICE.[speed] FROM
(SELECT * FROM DEVICES WHERE Device = 'Device 1') AS SINGLEDEVICE
WHERE Speed > 100
```

Comment: How many devices do you have?  How many rows are typically being returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create the following index

```
CREATE INDEX devices_device_speed
             ON devices
                (device,
                 speed);
```

and get rid of the subquery. At best it's optimized away or even slowing things down if not.

```
SELECT speed
       FROM devices
       WHERE device = 'Device 1'
             AND speed > 100;
```

Comment: if you have only a few devices you can also partition the table per device.

Answer (score 2):

Create index if not exist.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes I WHERE I.Name = 'NCIX_DEVICES_device_speed' AND I.object_id = OBJECT_ID('DEVICES'))
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIX_DEVICES_device_speed ON DEVICES ( Device,Speed)
GO
```

It is better to avoid sub-query if possible.

```
SELECT d.speed
FROM DEVICES d
WHERE d.device = 'Device 1'AND d.speed > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you searching from millions of records, Sqlserver introduce the [FTS(Full-Text Search)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017).

Its search using the keyword 'Contains', the syntax is

```
SELECT product_id   
FROM products   
WHERE CONTAINS(product_description, "Snap Happy 100EZ" )   
AND product_cost < 200 ;
```

Before the fts, use primary-key, proper foreign-key to fast more. For implementation points of view, it is very easy and given fast search for arbitrary search

It has pros and cons
[SQL Server Full Text Search Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555709/sql-server-full-text-search-performance)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The index wasnt correctly optimized.